# Let $h$ be such that $h(x)=\int_a^x f'(t)dt$. For which value of $a$ is function $h$ identical to function $f$?

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question

An informal reasoning had led me to the ( erroneous) conviction that: "the integral of the differential $f'(x)dx$ is identical to $f(x)$, because the (infinite) sum of the infinitesimal linear increments of function $f$ should (seemingly) equal the value of $f$".

In symbols, I thought that :

$$ \large \forall f \forall a \Large[ \int_a^x f'(t)dt = f(x)].$$

However, Desmos shew me that the assertion is not correct, and that the identity of the two functions ***depends on number $a$, the lower limit of integration***.

For example  if $f(x)=\cos(x)$, $h(x)=\int_0^x f'(t)dt \neq f(x)$, but rather $h(x)=f(x)-1$.

The identity occurs only if $a= \pi /2$.

Could you please explain what goes wrong in the informal reasoning above, and ***how to determine the value of the lower limit of integration at which the two functions are one and the same***?

In other words, how to ***solve for $a$*** the equation:

$$\Large \int_a^x f'(t)dt = f(x).$$

Below, a non-identity case, with $a=0$.

[image]

Comment: The correct formulation is $f(x)-f(a)=\int_a^x f'(y)\,dy$. This holds for all $x,a$ and all differentiable $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FTC tells you that
$$\int_a^x f'(t) \ \mathrm d t = f(x)-f(a)$$
hence this is equal to $f(x)$ if and only if $a$ is a zero of $f$, i.e. $f(a)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

By the FTC,

$$f(x) = h(x) = \int_a^x f’(t)\ \mathrm d t = f(x) - f(a) \iff f(a) = 0$$